# PHP Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting a warning from `PHP`:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ..

The code giving the warning is:

```
$saveData = array_map(array($connection, 'real_escape_string'), $saveData);
```

$saveData is decoded JSON taken from $_POST - typical dataset would be:

```
array(22) {
  ["quoteID"]=&gt;
  string(7) "GLY0YQ5"
  ["Inventory"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["pickupLocation"]=&gt;
  string(15) "EPPING NSW 2121"
  ["dropOffLocation"]=&gt;
  string(17) "RICHMOND VIC 3121"
  ["pickupSuburb"]=&gt;
  string(6) "EPPING"
  ["pickupPostcode"]=&gt;
  string(4) "2121"
  ["pickupState"]=&gt;
  string(3) "NSW"
  ["dropoffSuburb"]=&gt;
  string(8) "RICHMOND"
  ["dropoffPostcode"]=&gt;
  string(4) "3121"
  ["dropoffState"]=&gt;
  string(3) "VIC"
  ["pickupLatitude"]=&gt;
  string(10) "-33.772549"
  ["pickupLongitude"]=&gt;
  string(10) "151.082365"
  ["dropoffLatitude"]=&gt;
  string(10) "-37.818587"
  ["dropoffLongitude"]=&gt;
  string(10) "144.999181"
  ["pickupDistance"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
  ["pickupAccess"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
  ["dropoffDistance"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
  ["dropoffAccess"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
  ["regionalLoading"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
  ["totalVolume"]=&gt;
  string(2) "39"
  ["totalDistance"]=&gt;
  string(3) "897"
  ["totalPrice"]=&gt;
  string(4) "3120"
}
```

My understanding is the issue is `mysqli` expecting the first parameter to be the `$connection` variable, which it actually is, it's just different to the regular `mysqli` format because of the format required by `array_map`.

Given the outcome desired is the `real_escape` the entire array in one shot, and that the `error` is just a `warning` and is actually working, is there a better way to do this, and is it even necessary to make an adjustment?

Comment: What is `$saveData`? What values does it contain?

Comment: @deceze - I've added a typical breakdown of the `$saveData` into the question now.

Comment: BTW, why are you still using `real_escape_string` in the first place? Use prepared statements instead!

Comment: That's a fair statement, and I'm learning about prepared statements as we speak, but I'd still like to see if there's a solution to this problem if possible.

Comment: Removing the actual problem from the question makes it less useful to future readers. Rolled back to a consistent version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ["Inventory"]=>
>   array(0) {
>   }
> ```

Your problem is that your data contains an array, which cannot be escaped by `mysqli::real_escape_string` and which is triggering the warning. Make sure all values in the array are scalar values, not complex values like arrays, before attempting to escape them.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, as I `unset` that section from the array before I run it, so it's definitely not that. I've now deleted from above.. and apologies for not seeing that immediately.

Comment: The problem is that `Inventory` **is an array**. It doesn't matter whether it's empty or not. You're attempting to do `$connection->real_escape_string(array(...))`, which does not work.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't I get a fatal error and the script should fail? Everything appears to be working as it should, just with a warning. I should add I'm grateful for your help with this!

Comment: PHP likes to raise weak warnings over fatally crashing. You can debate the usefulness of that all day... -_-;;

Comment: I rechecked the code, and it turns out I wasn't unsetting the ['inventory'] section.. stupid, I know I went through the process in my head! Thank you very much for your help @deceze, it's much appreciated!